# rotating and appending matrix clockwise using matlab

Tags: matlab

I wanted to rotate a given matrix and append/concatenate at the same time as follows.

```
if in: [1]
then out: [1]

if in: [1,2; 3,4]
then out: [1,2,1; 3,4,3; 1,2,1]

if in: [1,2,3; 4,5,6]
then out: [1,2,3,2,1; 4,5,6,5,4; 1,2,3,2,1]

and so on...
```

Is there a way I can do it using matlab's built-in functions? If yes, could please show one without using any toolboxes, etc... Thanks.

Comment: I don't see rotation in your examples. You want a 90 degree rotation clockwise?  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @chappjc I did not mean the actual rotation, but the fact that the copy of the matrix is kind of rotated and appended. Thanks.

Comment: Got it.  Glad to help! It's a neat question by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve a symmetric replication of the matrix, down and right, which matches the example in the question:

```
a = [1,2,3; 4,5,6];
aRep = a([1:end end-1:-1:1],[1:end end-1:-1:1])
aRep =
     1     2     3     2     1
     4     5     6     5     4
     1     2     3     2     1
```

<s>Then to rotate, you can use `rot90(aRep,-1)` to rotate clockwise 90 degrees.</s>

Answer (score 0):

if A is your matrix:

```
n = size(A,1);
X = A(:,1:n-1);
Y = fliplr(X)
A = [A Y];

X = A(1:n-1,:);
Y = fliplr(X')';
A = [A; Y];
```

your final result should be in A.

You may find some syntax errors, I don't have matlab to check.